# Como salvar partes de um json em variavel?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, variáveis, console-application

Sou novo com programação e tenho um projeto em Aplicativo Console, que retorna a chamada de um API o Json dela. Gostaria de saber com qual comando eu consigo pegar apenas uma parte do json. Por exemplo:

```
      "amount": 4999,
      "currency": "BRL",
      "closed": true,
      "items": [
```

- Pegar só o campo `amount: 4999,` e salvar em uma variavel

Segue algumas informações a respeito do código, se precisarem de mais alguma informação me avisem por favor:

**Metodo da chamada da API que retorna o Json**

- O `console.write(response.content)` retorna o json que vem da API, parecido com o exemplo acima.

```
public class GetOrder
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public static void GetOrderId(string token, string url)
        {
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();
            Authenticator.Authorization();

            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient(url);
                //var request = new RestRequest(("orders/" + orderId), Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);
                var request = new RestRequest(("orders/"), Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);


                client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(token, auth.BasicAuthPassword);
                var response = client.Get(request);
                client.Execute(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Le o appsettings e criar um objeto IConfiguration
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                .Build();

            // Lê o valor da chave 
            var token = config.GetSection("Config:ApiTokenSecretQA").Value;
            var url = config.GetSection("Config:UrlApi").Value;

            // Passa como parâmetro
            GetOrder.GetOrderId(token, url);

            //GetOrder.GetOrderId();

            //CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
```

Comment: Qual a saída do comando ``Console.WriteLine(response.Content);``?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Sugiro que vc releia a sua pergunta e tente rescrevê-la para explicar mais claramente o que vc pretende fazer e qual o problema enfrentado. Além da pergunta não estar clara, o código apresentado também não tem muito sentido.

Comment: @HenriqueMiranda mencionei acima, editei o post.

Comment: @tvdias Editei o post, ve se ficou melhor de entender. Não sei qual parte do codigo possa ser mais util.

A pergunta mesmo é como salvar por exemplo, só uma linha do json ou apenas o valor de um campo do json em uma variavel. Ficou claro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parte relevante da pergunta está em fazer um pedido para uma api rest e desserializar o seu conteúdo.

Em relação ao código apresentado, só é preciso ter a parte abaixo em consideração:

```cs
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(("orders/"), Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);
//(...)
var response = client.Get(request);
client.Execute(request);
```

Para fazer o que pretende basta criar uma classe com as propriedades que pretende ler. Ex:

```cs
public class Retorno
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

E em seguida alterar a chamada à API para

```cs
var response = client.Execute<Retorno>(request);
var dados = response.Data;
```

A variável `dados` será do tipo `Retorno` e vc poderá acessar o valor em questão em `dados.Amount`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Foi exatamente isso que eu fiz! Mas agora to com um problema que preciso acessar um campo de um objeto que está dentro de outro:
```
"currency": "BRL",
      "closed": true,
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "oi_jskapkspaks",
          "type": "product"
        }
```
Tipo isso ai, nao consigo acessar os valores dentro do array "Items"

Comment: @GabrielRio se foi exatamente isso que vc fez, deverá marcar a resposta como aceita/fazer upvote na mesma. vou atualizar a resposta para mais essa sua necessidade, mas é importante sempre deixar todos os detalhes na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente para resolver seu problema precisamos entender como o JSON funciona. Quando você tem um retorno que é no formato JSON ele sempre vai ser acompanhado de uma chave e um valor no formato

**chave:valor**

Esse objeto pode ser Serializado e Deserializado através de uma classe no C# no seu exemplo nós teríamos uma classe parecida com:

```
public class Exemplo
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public List<object> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**OBS: Como não sei do que se trata a lista de Items eu deixei como object apenas para exemplificar.**

No caso quando ocorrer um retorno de uma API por exemplo o quando utilizarmos um método para deserializar esse JSON como por exemplo:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>();
```

Ele irá associar a **Chave** com a propriedade que possui o mesmo nome.

No seu caso como você quer somente o Amount você pode criar uma classe que possui somente essa propriedade.

```
public class RetornoAPI
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Outra saída que pode ser utilizada é com o Linq do Newtonsoft.

```
JObject resultado = JObject.Parse(json);
var value = resultado.GetValue("amount");
int amount = value.ToObject<int>();
```

No **GetValue()** a string tem que estar igual a do JSON se não ira retornar valor Null.

Comment: Muito obrigado, conseguiu resolver meu problema, e uma ótima explicação!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Comment: @GabrielRio note que não é necessário manipular o json diretamente, uma vez que é usado o `RestSharp`. Ao fazer isso ainda é possível optar por diferentes serializadores, como do `System.Text`, built in no dotnet.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode realizar diversas manipulações utilizando objetos json.
Pensando que o conteúdo da resposta HTTP é um texto (string) que contem um json essa linha de código abaixo converte este texto em um JObject

```cs
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
```

A partir desse momento você pode manipular o JObject pensando que o JSON trabalha com a lógica de chaves e valores, sendo da seguinte maneira:

```
{
"chave": valor,
...
}

jsonObject["chave"] -> Apresenta o valor
```

Logo, no seu exemplo, você pode acessar da seguinte maneira (Na segunda linha você estaria imprimindo no console o valor do amount, que no seu exemplo seria 4999:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

Console.WriteLine(jsonObject["amount"]);
```

Logo, o último passo seria criar uma variável para guardar esse valor, pensando que o amount é um valor numérico que pode ter casas decimais, usaria algum de ponto flutuante, por exemplo:

```
float amount = jsonObject["amount"];
```

Caso queira aprofundar mais seu código e fazer mais manipulações com o json, sugiro você dar uma olhada em serialização e Classes, para armazenar objetos mais complexos.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!