# Como pegar valor de um objeto interno em um arquivo Json?

Tags: c#, json, console-application

Gostaria de saber como fazer para acessar um objeto dentro do json, segue o codigo:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "or_asdasdasdasd",
      "code": "5d6f4sa56df",
      "amount": 800,
      "currency": "BRL",
      "closed": true,
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "oi_dasdasdasd",
          "type": "product",
          "description": "Renovação do APP",
          "amount": 200,
          "quantity": 4,
          "status": "active",
          "created_at": "2021-01-19T14:17:05Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-01-19T14:17:05Z",
          "code": "subscription"
        }
      ],
```

Esse Json é retornado de uma API que estou consultando, não está completo, só para passar a ideia mesmo.

Consigo acessar as 5 primeiros campos e seus valores, mas não consigo por exemplo acessar a Lista itens. segue meu código:

```
public static void SaveOrder(IRestResponse<Root> res)
        {
            OrderDbContext bd = new OrderDbContext();
            Order order = new Order();
            

            try
            {
                order.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                order.ExternalCodeId = res.Data.Code;
                order.ExternalCode = res.Data.Code;
                order.Currency = res.Data.Currency;
                order.ExternalProductCode = res.Data.Code;
                order.ProductDescription = res.Data.;     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                order.Amount = res.Data.Amount;
                //order.Quantity = res.Data.;
                order.ProductStatus = res.Data.Status;
                order.ProductCode = res.Data.Code;
                order.CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid();
                order.Status = res.Data.Status;
                order.CreatedAtLocal = res.Data.Created_at;
                order.UpdatedAtUTC = res.Data.Updated_at;
                order.ClosedAt = res.Data.Closed_at;
                order.ChargeId = Guid.NewGuid();

                bd.Order.Add(order);
                bd.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Marquei com uma seta onde não consigo acessar os campos. Esse método ele salva as informações no banco de dados.

Comment: O seu json está assim mesmo?  Porque ` "data": [` seria um `array`, e não um objeto.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sim, o json é exatamente assim, ai dentro desse Data fica todos os OrderID. Esse Order é apenas um, e pela metade. Tudo que está dentro do objeto Data eu consigo acessar, os que estao mais encapsulados nao consigo.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como salvar partes de um json em variavel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490603/como-salvar-partes-de-um-json-em-variavel)

Comment: O seu código não condiz com o JSON apresentado a menos que você tenha uma interação anterior ou esteja passando apenas uma posição para `SaveOrder()`... E você deveria utilizar a mesma estratégia para o `ProductDescription`

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, você precisa acessar um **array dentro de um array**, algo como:

`if (order.Data[0].Items.Length > 0) {`

`order.ProductDescription = res.Data.FirstOrDefault().Items.FirstOrDefault()?.Description;`

ou

`order.ProductDescription = res.Data[0].Items[0].Description;`

`}`

Imagino que seja algo assim dado ao JSON que colocou como exemplo, por mais que já tenham apontado que a forma como está acessando as propriedades não esteja "batendo" com o documento. Seu JSON tem o "data" como um array, então seu primeiro acesso à uma propriedade dentro da propriedade "data" seria:

`order.Data.FirstOrDefault().Code`

ou

`order.Data[0].Code`

**As propridades "Data" e "Items" deveriam ser listas ou arrays de acordo com seu JSON, então deveriam estar sendo acessadas como uma lista/array.**

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Obs: é necessário importar o namespace `System.Linq` para usar o método de extensão `FirstOrDefault()`